# FileSystemAPI in Chrome Android

Tags: android, google-chrome, fileapi

Does Chrome on the Android support the Full FileSystemAPI. Specifically, I need the FileWriter and the ability to create directories. caniuse.com is not helping on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it should work as same as you would expect on desktop Chrome.